# Printing warning to stderr if -W error is enabled on pytest

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

I need to fail my tests when warning is occur. I enable `-W error` in pytest config but in this case warning is not printed to `stderr`. 
How can I print warnings to stderr even if warning throws exception?

Once again: I need both printing to stderr and throwing an exception when warning is occur.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Assuming you want to do this all the time, the easiest way to do this might be to annotate the test module with:

```
   # turns all warnings into errors for this module
   pytestmark = pytest.mark.filterwarnings('error')
```

Reference:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html#pytest-mark-filterwarnings

Comment: It seems it isn't what I asked about. In this case warning will throw exception and still will not be printed to stderr. Please correct me if i'm not right

Comment: Sorry if my answer was not helpful, but I thought failing the test was the most important characteristic. If you provide '-s' as a parameter stdin, stdout, and stderr should be printed.

Further, if you are interested in the log message, the caplog fixture is available.